# How to combine select max and sum oracle with 2 tables? error ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I have a query:

```
select a.id_obj, 
       b.name_obj,
       max(sum(a.tot_obj)) 
  from detailsell a, object b
 group by a.id_obj 
 where a.id_obj = b.id_obj;
```

and I get an error `ORA-00933: sql command not properly ended.`

**Sample data:**

```
table "object":
-------------------
 id_obj | name_obj
-------------------
   01   |    a
   02   |    b
-------------------

table "detailsell":
------------------------------
 id_detail | id_obj | tot_obj
------------------------------
     51    |   01   |    2
     52    |   01   |    3
     53    |   02   |    4
------------------------------
```

I want get the sum from `tot_obj` and then get the max value, grouped by `id_obj`. And I want to show `name_obj` from `id_obj`.

**Hence, I expect the query to return:**

```
 id_obj | name_obj | tot_obj
-----------------------------
    01  |    a     |    5
```

Comment: not sure what you're looking for? do you want the sum and maximum of tot_obj column, or do you want to sum up the maximum values? or do you want the largest sum?

Comment: and since you're only grouping by id_obj, you need to apply an aggregate function to name_obj.

Comment: like I said, don't know what `max(sum(a.tot_obj))` means

Comment: i want to get name_obj from max(sum(a.tot_obj)) . where name_obj from table object and tot_obj from table detailsell.

Comment: i want get sum from tot_obj and get max value . group by id_obj. and i want to show name_obj from id_obj. sorry my bad eng

Comment: It might help if you post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: edit done. i want to show id_obj with a max of tot_obj

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have capitalised the 'I's and restructured your sentence to correct the English.  I have also copied yur comment to the question.  It makes it easier for someone else to answer it, the don't have to read all the comments.  If you like, you can delete that comment now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct reason of error is that you put `group by` clause before `where`. Also it is strongly advised to use ANSI joins instead 
of putting them in `where`. And to the goal, typical way to deal with such tasks is:

```
select a.id_obj, a.name_obj, sum(b.tot_obj) as tot_obj 
  from object a join detailsell b on a.id_obj = b.id_obj
  group by a.id_obj, a.name_obj
  having sum(b.tot_obj) = (select max(sum(tot_obj)) from detailsell group by id_obj);
```

or more modern, usually faster, with analytic functions (here I used `rank`):

```
select id_obj,name_obj, tot_obj 
  from (
    select a.id_obj, a.name_obj, sum(b.tot_obj) as tot_obj,
           rank() over (order by sum(b.tot_obj) desc) as rnk
     from object a join detailsell b on a.id_obj = b.id_obj
     group by a.id_obj, a.name_obj)
  where rnk = 1;
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo for both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5695d/1)</sup>

You can also use `max() ... keep dense rank ...` or `row_number() ...` or other analytic functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab and assume you want the id and name of the item with the largest sum, which you can do with:

```
select id_obj, min(name_obj), max(tot_obj) tot_obj
from (select a.id_obj, min(b.name_obj), sum(a.tot_obj) tot_obj 
      from detailsell a join object b using (id_brg)
      group by id_obj) x
group by id_obj;
```